# How to invoke 'nuget restore' in order to restore to a specific directory, specific packages, hosted in in-house nuget servers

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget, nuget-package-restore

Assume we have the following package.config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <packages>
      <package id="MSBuildTasks" version="1.5.0.235" developmentDependency="true"  />
      <package id="Foo.Bar" version="6.0.2" />
      <package id="Foo.Ping" version="3.4.3" />
    </packages>
```

We want to pull MSBuildTasks from nuget.org to folder 'packages' and Foo.Bar from an in-house nuget server to folder 'packages.inhouse'. How can one go about doing this without generating warnings?

I know one could use 'nuget restore ' with two separate nuget-config-files (+ suppress all errors in the command line).

This technique works but it's bound to generate warnings [*] in the build system about packages not being found (in the first invocation Foo.Bar and Foo.Ping obviously don't exist in Nuget.org and in the second invocation 'MSBuildTasks' obviously doesn't exist in the in-house server).

I am annoyed by the phantom warnings of such an approach, so I'd just like to know whether there's something better out there.

[*] yes I am aware that one can suppress warnings in msbuild ala

```
   <Exec ContinueOnError="true" StandardOutputImportance="low" StandardErrorImportance="low"   Command=" nuget restore <config file>" />
```

but still common ...